# Sequence animations inside CSSTransitionGroup

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

We are working on a project with some challenging animation requirements.We are trying to do the animations in CSS and not get JS involved in the animation work. For example we have the following component (simplified for clarity):

```
    var mainMenu = React.createClass({
    mixins: [PureRenderMixin],
    render: function () {
        var _this = this;
        var currItem;
        var items = this.props.itemList.map(function (item) {
            if (!item.get('isOpen')) {
                currItem = <MainMenuClosed key={item.get('MenuItemId')}
                                           menuTypeId={item.get('MenuTypeId')}
                                           title={item.get('ItemTitle')}
                                           text={item.get('ItemText')}
                                           imageUrl={item.get('ImageId')}
                                           clickHandler={_this.props.closedClickHandler} />;
            } else {
                currItem = <MainMenuOpen menuTypeId={item.get('MenuTypeId')}
                     key={item.get('MenuItemId')}
                                         clickHandler={_this.props.openClickHandler}
                                         items={item.get('children')}
                                          />;
            }

            return (
                currItem
            );
        })
        return (
             <ReactCSSTransitionGroup component="div" className="row" transitionName="mainMenuItems">
                {items}
            </ReactCSSTransitionGroup>
        );
    }
});
```

When a menu item is clicked an action is called, which fetches some stuff from the server and sends it on to the stores. The problem is that once the re-render happens the leaving component fades out for example and the entering component fades in at the same time. I would like to let the leaving component finish its animation sequence and then have the entering menu item begin its animation. Is there a builtin way to create such a sequence?

Comment: If you do not want to touch JS, then you could set css fade-out to e.g. 500ms, and set a start-delay on fade-in of 500ms in css.

Comment: @wintvelt - Sorry, maybe I didn't articulate this point... I have no problem doing the orchestration logic in JS. I would rather not do the animation itself in JS.

Comment: I see. I would still recommend to do 1 animation cycle and do a delay on the fade-in animation. All in css.